# ¿Con que tipo de dato debo de almacenar una Huella dactilar, Código QR y Código de Barras en Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, qrcode, código-de-barras, huelladigital

Necesito crear una base de datos donde almacenare lo siguiente:

- Huella Dactilar.
- Código QR
- Código de barras

Todo esto lo haré en postgresql , pero desconozco que tipo de dato debo de utilizar para almacenarlo

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si al consideras que son información de tipo binaria(archivos/imágenes) puedes usar el tipo de dato [bytea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html)

Pero como consejo te comento que si son datos binarios muy grande hagas un análisis de si vas a almacenarlo en la base de datos, pues eso puede traer problemas de rendimiento en el futuro